# Login form briefly reappears when user logs in -- what is causing this?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

**I have a login screen that briefly flashes after the user logs in. This doesn't happen all the time, but it's annoying. I am having trouble figuring out what is causing this and so I thought I'd ask the great people of stackoverflow to see if they have any tips on how to fix or troubleshoot. Thanks!**

Here's my issue (as shown in screenshots with some code below):

> User logs in:

[image]

> User sees spinner as his credentials are authenticated:

[image]

> User sees login screen flash briefly again before router redirects him to the requested content.
>   [image]
>
> Here is code for the `Login.vue` page:

```
<template>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <template v-if="isLoading">
      <spinner key="spinner"></spinner>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <div key="form">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <aside class="alert alert-danger" v-if="error">
          {{ error }}
        </aside>
        <form @submit.prevent="handlerLogin">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" v-model="formData.email" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" v-model="formData.password" />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Login',
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      formData: {
        email: null,
        password: null
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    error() {
      return this.$store.state.error
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async handlerLogin() {
      this.isLoading = true
      try {
        const payload = {
          email: this.formData.email,
          password: this.formData.password
        }
        await this.$store.dispatch('logInUser', payload)
        console.log('ready to fetch user profile')
        await this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
        this.$router.replace('photos')
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      } finally {
        this.isLoading = false
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

> And here is the `logInUser` action code from Vuex store:

```
async logInUser({ commit }, payload) {
  commit('CLEAR_ERROR')
  try {
    const user = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
    commit('SET_CURRENT_USER', user.user)
  } catch (error) {
    commit('SET_ERROR', error)
  } 
}
```

Comment: Well, obviously the `this.isLoading = false`, since that is what is in your `v-if`. Have you considered adding a third state "isLoggedIn", that just displays a message in the line of "You have been authenticated. We are loading the photos". Or moving the `this.isLoading` line to the catch, so your component is forever in the loading animation until the router loads the other view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the mistake you are making is that you expect `this.$router.replace` to be blocking, which it is not. ([docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-replace-location-oncomplete-onabort)) As such, the `this.isLoading = false` from `finally` is called immediately after. Sometimes Vue manages to re-render your component before the router finishes transitioning to the new view, and sometimes it does not.

You can create a third state that simply checks if the user is logged in and displays an appropriate message. Keep in mind that if the user gets on the log-in page when logged in, this needs to do something sensible as well. An other option is to move `this.isLoading = false` to the catch, but keep in mind that if navigation fails, for example due to a (global) route guard, your component is loading eternally without clear feedback what happened. A third option would be to make `this.$router.replace` blocking by wrapping it in a Promise or something:

```js
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.$router.replace('photos', resolve, reject)
})
```